# angular material checkbox and radio button not working properly

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material

I am using angular material from https://material.angular.io .

I followed the steps in getting started and added all dependencies. Everything works fine except checkboxes and buttons.

When I use the syntax mentioned here https://material.angular.io/components/component/checkbox for checkboxes I am getting two checkboxes as shown below

[image]

Also I am not getting any ripple styles. Same thing with radio buttons. Can someone help me how to solve this?

Below is my code for app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
import { SampleComponent } from './sample/sample.component';
import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SampleComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularMaterialTest</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<md-checkbox>Check me!</md-checkbox>
```

Comment: did you include `material` files and css in your app?

Comment: please provide code snippets where material is included in your app

Comment: I added code. Also I installed @angular/material, @angular/animations node packages

Comment: If you hit F12 do you see any JavaScript errors or 404s?

Comment: I am getting that GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css 
material.es5.js:148 Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming . But when replaced with <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" /> no console error. But the problem is not solved.

Comment: I copied the file from node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css to assets folder, changed the path in index.html and it's working perfect. But still do not know why it is not working from node_modules folder. Is the default path generated by npm wrong?

Comment: i dont think so, it works fine for me. Is your issue solved? If not, can you try importing `MaterialModule` in your `aap` component?

Comment: I tried importing MaterialModule in my app component. But it did not solve the issue. Do not know why the link "http://localhost:4200/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" is giving 404 !

Comment: Hey Amit, by any change did you figure out the solution for this. I am having the same problem with Material 5.1.0.

Comment: I am also having a similar problem with 11.2.12. The button won't select or fill when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

May have come 8 months late but your import 'hammerjs'; is written in the wrong folder, it should be placed in main.ts file.
You can try this guide, there's a video to watch as well
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/113/How-to-Build-an-Angular-5-Material-App

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with my **Angular material radio button not working**. I found that it was a CSS issue where the inner elements within the radio button weren't filling correctly even though they operated fine.

styles.scss:

```
.mat-radio-inner-circle {
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   background-color: navy;
 }
```

It is important to ensure all elements you want **visible**

- **Have a height, width, and background-color**
- **Aren't hidden**